# Is there a way to see a D7200's serial number on screen to quickly check authenticity?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d7000

We can see the serial number of some cameras on the LCD display while it's on. That is a hard thing to fake. 
Does the Nikon D7200 (or any model similar to this one) have this same capability of having the serial number available in one of the displays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to see a Nikon's serial number on screen.

However, the serial number is embedded in the EXIF data of photos taken by their DSLR, mirrorless, and bridge cameras (I'm not sure if the serial number is also in their compact cameras). You can extract this EXIF field (either `Serial Number` or `Camera Serial Number`) using the excellent [`exiftool`](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) software by Phil Harvey. (I am sure there are other tools that will display this EXIF tag as well).

Comment: Thank you,  @scottbb. Is this what you referred to? 
 http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/
The camera I am thinking about buying is D7200 (so I can use some of my old lenses)
So once I see the metadata of a picture, will I be able to see the Serial Number? Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Indeed, that's the `exiftool` I was referring to

Answer (score 2):

Not on screen but, I have a D7000 and serial number for that camera is in the EXIF data of each image it takes. GIMP can view/edit metadata. For my D7000 camera...

1. Open JPG/RAW image in GIMP
2. Menu --> *Image/Metadata/View Metadata*
3. Select "*Exif*" tab at top
4. Look in "*Exif Tag*" column
5. Scroll down and look for "*Exif.Nikon3.SerialNumber*"
6. The number in the "*Value*" column is the serial number.
7. That number should match the number on the base of the actual camera body. If it doesn't then you have a fake.

Hope that helps.